# Specify local XSD schema in XML file

Tags: eclipse, xsd

I need to validate an XML file and using eclipse to do it. I've added the XML file and all XSD file to a project:
[image]

I've added a reference to the XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S2SDDDnf:MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb xmlns = "MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb.xsd">


    <S2SDDDnf:SndgInst>stuff</S2SDDDnf:SndgInst>
    <S2SDDDnf:RcvgInst>stuff</S2SDDDnf:RcvgInst>
    <S2SDDDnf:SrvcId>COR</S2SDDDnf:SrvcId>
    <S2SDDDnf:TstCode>T</S2SDDDnf:TstCode>
    <S2SDDDnf:FType>DNF</S2SDDDnf:FType>
    <S2SDDDnf:FileRef>DNFMJMD%R5%LXXX</S2SDDDnf:FileRef>
    <S2SDDDnf:FileBusDt>2013-10-18</S2SDDDnf:FileBusDt>
    <S2SDDDnf:RoutingInd>ALL</S2SDDDnf:RoutingInd>
    <S2SDDDnf:FileCycleNo>01</S2SDDDnf:FileCycleNo>
    <S2SDDDnf:NumDDBlk>1</S2SDDDnf:NumDDBlk>
    <S2SDDDnf:NumPCRBlk>0</S2SDDDnf:NumPCRBlk>
    <S2SDDDnf:NumREJBlk>0</S2SDDDnf:NumREJBlk>

    <S2SDDDnf:FIToFICstmrDrctDbt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.003.001.02"
                          xmlns:S2SDDDnf="urn:S2SDDDnf:xsd:$MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb">

    <GrpHdr>
        <MsgId>DNF.UAIAO47X2B</MsgId>
        <CreDtTm>2013-10-18T15:40:00</CreDtTm>
        <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
        <TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">1025.00</TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt>
        <IntrBkSttlmDt>2013-10-22</IntrBkSttlmDt>
        <SttlmInf>
            <SttlmMtd>CLRG</SttlmMtd>
            <ClrSys>
                <Prtry>ST2</Prtry>
            </ClrSys>
        </SttlmInf>
        <InstdAgt>
            <FinInstnId>
                <BIC>stuff</BIC>
            </FinInstnId>
        </InstdAgt>
    </GrpHdr>

<DrctDbtTxInf>
    <PmtId>
        <InstrId>DDPreTest18</InstrId>
      <EndToEndId>TS141GENR-ZLDL%R5%WXXX</EndToEndId>
      <TxId>TRXID01.R8NRO%R4%D</TxId>
    </PmtId>
    <PmtTpInf>
        <SvcLvl>
            <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
        </SvcLvl>
        <LclInstrm>
            <Cd>CORE</Cd>
        </LclInstrm>
        <SeqTp>OOFF</SeqTp>
    </PmtTpInf>
    <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">1025.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
    <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
    <ReqdColltnDt>2013-10-22</ReqdColltnDt>
    <DrctDbtTx>
        <MndtRltdInf>
            <MndtId>Mndt141.001b</MndtId>
            <DtOfSgntr>2013-09-16</DtOfSgntr>
            <AmdmntInd>false</AmdmntInd>
            <AmdmntInfDtls>
                <OrgnlCdtrSchmeId>
                    <Id>
                        <PrvtId>
                            <Othr>
                                <Id></Id>
                            </Othr>
                        </PrvtId>
                    </Id>
                </OrgnlCdtrSchmeId>
            </AmdmntInfDtls>
        </MndtRltdInf>
        <CdtrSchmeId>
            <Id>
                <PrvtId>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>stuff</Id>
                        <SchmeNm><Prtry>SEPA</Prtry></SchmeNm>
                    </Othr>
                </PrvtId>
            </Id>
        </CdtrSchmeId>
    </DrctDbtTx>
    <Cdtr>
        <Nm>stuff</Nm>
    </Cdtr>
    <CdtrAcct>
        <Id>
            <IBAN>stuff</IBAN>
        </Id>
    </CdtrAcct>
    <CdtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
            <BIC>stuff</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
    </CdtrAgt>
    <Dbtr>
        <Nm>stuff</Nm>
    </Dbtr>
    <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
            <IBAN>stuff</IBAN>
        </Id>
    </DbtrAcct>
    <DbtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
            <BIC>stuff</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
    </DbtrAgt>
    <RmtInf>
        <Ustrd>Pre-testing SEPA Direct Debits</Ustrd>
    </RmtInf>
</DrctDbtTxInf>
</S2SDDDnf:FIToFICstmrDrctDbt>
</S2SDDDnf:MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb>
```

And this is the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- STEP2 SDD Schema, MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb, May 25th 2012,  Release November 2012  -->
<!-- STEP2 SDD Shift camt.056 after pacs.003 in sequence and counter, February 25th 2010 -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sw3="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.003.001.02" xmlns:sw2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.002.001.03" xmlns:sw6="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.056.001.01" xmlns:S2SDDDnf="urn:S2SDDDnf:xsd:$MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb" targetNamespace="urn:S2SDDDnf:xsd:$MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.003.001.02" schemaLocation="pacs.003.001.02.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.002.001.03" schemaLocation="pacs.002.001.03.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.056.001.01" schemaLocation="camt.056.001.01.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SndgInst" type="sw3:BICIdentifier"/>
                <xs:element name="RcvgInst" type="sw3:BICIdentifier"/>
                <!-- changed from SrvcID to SrvcId, Febrary 12 2009 -->
                <xs:element name="SrvcId" type="S2SDDDnf:SrvcID"/>
                <xs:element name="TstCode" type="S2SDDDnf:TestCodeType"/>
                <xs:element name="FType" type="S2SDDDnf:FTpType"/>
                <xs:element name="FileRef" type="S2SDDDnf:Max16Text"/>
                <xs:element name="FileBusDt" type="sw2:ISODate"/>
                <xs:element name="RoutingInd" type="S2SDDDnf:RoutingInd"/>
                <xs:element name="FileCycleNo" type="S2SDDDnf:Max2NumericText"/>
                <xs:element name="NumDDBlk" type="S2SDDDnf:Max8NumericText"/>
                <xs:element name="NumPCRBlk" type="S2SDDDnf:Max8NumericText"/>
                <xs:element name="NumREJBlk" type="S2SDDDnf:Max8NumericText"/>
                <xs:element name="FIToFICstmrDrctDbt" type="sw3:FIToFICustomerDirectDebitV02" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <!--camt.056.001.01 replace pacs.006.001.02, January 20th 2010 -->
                <xs:element name="FIToFIPmtCxlReq" type="sw6:FIToFIPaymentCancellationRequestV01" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="FIToFIPmtStsRpt" type="sw2:FIToFIPaymentStatusReportV03" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="Max16Text">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-Z]{16,16}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="SrvcID">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="COR"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="B2B"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="FTpType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="DNF"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TestCodeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="T"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="P"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="Max8NumericText">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1,8}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="RoutingInd">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="3" fixed="true"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="DIR"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="IND"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="ALL"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="Max2NumericText">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2,2}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

And getting this error:

```
The prefix "S2SDDDnf" for element "S2SDDDnf:MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb" is not bound.    SDDCoreTest18.xml   /XMLValidation  line 2  XML Problem
```

**Edit**
Organize the XSD files in separate folder:
[image]

Comment: Please provide both the XSD and XML in non-image form.  Both should be complete, or as complete as necessary to exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a definition of the  S2SDDDnf alias like so:

```
<S2SDDDnf:MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb xmlns = "MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb.xsd" xmlns:S2SDDDnf="urn:S2SDDDnf:xsd:$MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb">...</S2SDDDnf:MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb>
```

Comment: One more questions, If I wanted to stick all the XSD files in a folder, how would I do that? I tried something like xmlns = "XSDFILES/MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb.xsd" xmlns:S2SDDDnf="urn:S2SDDDnf:xsd:$XSDFILES/MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb" but it didn't work.

Comment: @Yoav, I am not sure what you're trying to achieve with `xmlns = "XSDFILES/MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb.xsd" ` but you have to remember that xmlns declaration has nothing to do with XSD file location. One is an XML artifact, which associates a moniker with a URI, while XSD file location is specific to XSD only, and for that you use [XML Schema Instance schemaLocation and noNamespaceSchemaLocation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#no-xsi). To have a more "transparent" way to validate XMLs, regardless where your XSDs are, I recommend [Eclipse's XML Catalog](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_XML_Catalog)

Comment: I want to seperate the XSD files from the XML files so tried putting all the XSD files in a folder (see new screenshot). I though that adding xmlns = "MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb.xsd" xmlns:S2SDDDnf="urn:S2SDDDnf:xsd:$MPEDDDnfBlkDirDeb" tells eclipse which XSD file to look for, and that it assumes its on the same folder as the XML file, so tried to add the folder to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a XML file referencing the XSD using the New XML File wizard.